# Invalid content was found starting with element 'jdbc-ee:postgresql-data-source'

Tags: java, postgresql, mule

I'm trying to add a PostgreSQL JDBC connector to my app, but it cannot start.
The connector and data source was added by the Mule studio, which does not see a problem.
This app was running correctly before I've tried to add the database access functionality.

This is the error I get after starting the app:

```
ERROR 2014-11-01 15:14:46,389 [Mule.app.deployer.monitor.1.thread.1] org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentService: Failed to deploy application archive: myapp.zip
org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'jdbc-ee:postgresql-data-source'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":beans, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context":property-placeholder, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":ref, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":global-property, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":configuration, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":notifications, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-extension, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-extension, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-agent, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-security-manager, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-transaction-manager, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-connector, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-global-endpoint, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-exception-strategy, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-flow-construct, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":flow, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":sub-flow, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-model, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-interceptor-stack, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-filter, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-transformer, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":processor-chain, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":custom-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":invoke, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-global-intercepting-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":custom-queue-store, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-processing-strategy}' is expected.
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:220)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.ApplicationWrapper.init(ApplicationWrapper.java:64)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultMuleDeployer.deploy(DefaultMuleDeployer.java:46)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentService.guardedDeploy(DeploymentService.java:398)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentService.deploy(DeploymentService.java:365)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentService$AppDirWatcher.run(DeploymentService.java:685)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

and part of mflow file which do not pass the validation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:jdbc-ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/jdbc" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:tcp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tcp" xmlns:sftp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sftp" xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns:cxf="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf" xmlns:jms="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms" xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:core="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="EE-3.4.1" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/current/mule-vm.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tcp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tcp/current/mule-tcp.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sftp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sftp/current/mule-sftp.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf/current/mule-cxf.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms/current/mule-jms.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/jdbc http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/jdbc/current/mule-jdbc-ee.xsd">
...
    <jdbc-ee:postgresql-data-source name="My_Data_Source" user="usr123" password="pwd123"  transactionIsolation="UNSPECIFIED" doc:name="PostgreSQL Data Source" url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/MyDB"/>
...
```

Can you see what I've missed, please?

Comment: Which version of Mule are you using .. community Edition or Enterprise Edition ?

Comment: It is community version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Mule Community Edition and using PostgreSQL JDBC connector :- `<jdbc-ee:postgresql-data-source.` which is of Enterprise Edition ..

Use Mule Studio community Edition Database Connector or if you want to use `<jdbc-ee:postgresql-data-source`.. use Mule Enterprise Edition ..

Comment: Thank you! How can I configure the community connector? I do not see an option in the Mule Studio. Mule Studio is version 3.5.

Comment: If you use Community Edition .. you will find DB connector for Community version .. If you are unable to find it, then you have 2 options :- 1)Use Mule Enterprise Edition Studio or 2) Use Spring Beans in Community Edition to configure your Data source and provide you url,username,password in the spring beans

Comment: I do not plan to use the enterprise edition. I'm trying to use the generic JDBC connector, but they say it will be deprecated in the next version. So I suppose having a bean is better option for the future, in case there will be no option to use the Generic JDBC connector later, am I right?